# Eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of a family of pentadiagonal matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a square matrix of order $n\times n$ such that $a_{ij}=1$ if $j=i+2$ or $i=j+2$; otherwise it is $0$.

I want to find the generalized formula for the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: Which direction of research have you taken ?

Comment: Why don't you answer my question ? If you answer it, I could hopefuly help you...

Comment: I have added the word "pentadiagona" matrix to your title.

Comment: If $n$ is odd, the matrix can be considered a block-tridiagonal matrix with simple $2\times 2$ blocks. An explicit form of eigenvalues is e.g. [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0096300320302903)

Answer (score 2):

Hint (Too long for a comment) :

You are looking for a general (closed-form) formula for the eigenvalues of this pentagonal matrix. I don't know if such a formula exists, but, maybe, having particular cases may help you in your quest.

With a little "Sage" program, I have obtained the factorized version of the characteristic polynomials up to $n=15$ of these matrices $n \times n$ evidencing that in most cases the (real, of course) eigenvalues are rather simple (even when they are "double" :)) :

$$\begin{cases}
P_3(x)&=& (x + 1)(x - 1)x\\
P_4(x)&=& (x + 1)^2(x - 1)^2\\
P_5(x)&=& (x^2 - 2)(x + 1)(x - 1)x\\
P_6(x)&=&  (x^2 - 2)^2x^2\\
P_7(x)&=& (x^2 + x - 1)(x^2 - x - 1)(x^2 - 2)x\\
P_8(x)&=& (x^2 + x - 1)^2(x^2 - x - 1)^2\\
P_9(x)&=& (x^2 + x - 1)(x^2 - x - 1)(x^2 - 3)(x + 1)(x - 1)x\\
P_{10}(x)&=&(x^2 - 3)^2(x + 1)^2(x - 1)^2x^2\\
P_{11}(x)&=&(x^3 + x^2 - 2x - 1)(x^3 - x^2 - 2x + 1)(x^2 - 3)(x + 1)(x - 1)x\\
P_{12}(x)&=&(x^3 + x^2 - 2x - 1)^2(x^3 - x^2 - 2x + 1)^2\\
P_{13}(x)&=&(x^4 - 4x^2 + 2)(x^3 + x^2 - 2x - 1)(x^3 - x^2 - 2x + 1)(x^2 - 2)x\\
P_{14}(x)&=&(x^4 - 4x^2 + 2)^2(x^2 - 2)^2x^2\\
P_{15}(x)&=&(x^4 - 4x^2 + 2)(x^3 - 3x + 1)(x^3 - 3x - 1)(x^2 - 2)(x + 1)(x - 1)x\end{cases}$$

Comment: Among the results one can obtain : $\pm 2\cos(\pi/5)$ are eigenvalues for $n=7,8,9$, more generaly $\pm 2\cos(\pi/k)$ look eigenvalues for $n=(2k-3), (2k-2),(2k-1)$...